# Multiple select statements with SUM() and WHERE?

Tags: mysql

This involves three columns 'name', 'trans_status', 'amount'.  I need to get a table where each 'name' is on one row, and there's a SUM() of all amounts for each of four statuses (new, pending, final, closed).

Here's what I'm looking for:

```
name           total_new     total_pending       total_final      total_closed
Frank          145.35        219.34              518.23           9588.33
Susan          233.54        455.44              920.00           9600.52
```

Here's what my table looks like:

```
transactions
================
userid        status        amount
----------------------------------
1             new           25.00
1             new           30.18
2             final         90.12
1             pending       100.25
2             new           81.43

users
================
userid        name
----------------------------------
1             Frank
2             Susan
```

I've tried a bunch of different queries, but I'm afraid I'm beyond my abilities.  Here's one failing example:

```
    SELECT a.userid, u.name, 
    ( SUM(a.amount)
      WHERE a.status = 'new' 
    ) AS total_new,
    ( SUM(a.amount)
      WHERE a.status = 'pending' 
    ) AS total_pending,
    ( SUM(a.amount)
      WHERE a.status = 'final' 
    ) AS total_final,
    ( SUM(a.amount)
      WHERE a.status = 'closed' 
    ) AS total_closed 
    FROM transactions AS a
    LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.userid = a.userid
    GROUP BY u.name
    ORDER BY u.name ASC;
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select u.name,
sum(case when status = 'new' then amount else 0 end) as total_new,
sum(case when status = 'pending' then amount else 0 end) as total_pending,
sum(case when status = 'final' then amount else 0 end) as total_final,
sum(case when status = 'closed' then amount else 0 end) as total_closed
from users as u
left join transactions as t on u.userid = t.userid
group by u.name
```

Comment: @MikeP, as courtesy to people answering questions, and those looking for unanswered, click the checkmark to the left of the answer that solved your question.  It gives points to the poster, and prevents others from trying to answer an already solved one.  It also helps others looking for similar to know what worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

am not sure try this:

```
SELECT a.userid, u.name, 
    (SELECT SUM(amount) AS total_new FROM transactions
      WHERE status = 'new' 
    ),
    (SELECT SUM(amount) AS total_pending FROM transactions
      WHERE status = 'pending' 
    ),
    (SELECT SUM(amount) AS total_final FROM transactions
      WHERE status = 'final' 
    ),
    (SELECT SUM(amount) AS total_closed FROM transactions
      WHERE status = 'closed' 
    ) 
    FROM transactions AS a
    LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.userid = a.userid
    GROUP BY u.name
    ORDER BY u.name ASC;
```